# Can someone explain this Python re.sub() unexpected output?

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python 2.6 and am getting [what I think is] unexpected output from re.sub()

```
>>> re.sub('[aeiou]', '-', 'the cat sat on the mat')
'th- c-t s-t -n th- m-t'
>>> re.sub('[aeiou]', '-', 'the cat sat on the mat', re.IGNORECASE)
'th- c-t sat on the mat'
```

If this output is what is expected, what is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the fourth parameter is count, not flags. You're telling it to apply the pattern twice (re.IGNORECASE = 2).

Comment: Ah yes. Mixing up parameters. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To pass flags you can use re.compile

```
expression = re.compile('[aeiou]', re.IGNORECASE)
expression.sub('-', 'the cat sat on the mat')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you've upgraded since asking this question. If you are using Python 2.7+, you don't need to use `re.compile`. You can call `sub` and specify `flags` with a named argument.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[aeiou]', '-', 'the cat sat on the mat', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'th- c-t s-t -n th- m-t'
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub